# SELECT sum of column in all databases

Tags: mysql

I want to see sum of orders from all my databases to get some insight. Right now I have a query that lists database_name and table correctly.

```
SELECT table_schema AS database_name, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name =  "shopping_carts";
```

What I want is some kind of query where I would do something like this.

```
SELECT table_schema as database_name, SUM(shopping_carts.sub_total)........
```

How would one query something like this?

**EDIT**: What I  want to see is:

**l database_name l SUM(column_name) l**

```
| database_name1 |   114728   | ##sum of database_name1.shopping_carts.column_name
| database_name2 |   252154   | ##sum of database_name2.shopping_carts.column_name
| database_name4 |    48156   | ## etc.
| database_name5 |    18448   | ## etc.
```

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: You could build a prepared statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html unioning all your tables before aggregating.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use a single table `shopping_charts`, where you add a column named, for example, `database_name`. This would make queries easier to write and to mantain, and properly optimized.

While not optimal, you can solve your problem with a dynamic query, for example this query will return the list of selects you have to perform on each database:

```
select
  concat(
    'select ''', table_schema, ''' AS database_name,'
    'sum(sub_total)',
    ' from ', table_schema, '.shopping_charts'
  )
from
  information_schema.tables
where
  table_name = "shopping_carts"
```

then you can use group_concat to obtain a single sql statement:

```
select group_concat(sql_single_db separator ' union all ') as sql_all_db
from (
  select
    concat(
      'select ''', table_schema, ''' AS database_name,'
      'sum(sub_total)',
      ' from ', table_schema, '.shopping_charts'
    ) sql_single_db
  from
    information_schema.tables
  where
    table_name = "shopping_charts"
) s into @sql_all_db;
```

which you can execute with:

```
prepare stmt1 from @sql_all_db;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```